# Google Apps Script code to delete rows based on partial cell data

Tags: google-apps-script, delete-row

I'm trying to delete rows based on partial cell data contained in cells in column A. For example a cell might contain a value "OX USPEA", cylinder part number, I work in the gas industry, and I want to delete any row that contains this value. There are nearly 200 rows out of about 500 that I'm working with that contain the beginning text "OX USPE" but end in various different text combinations. This is a snipet of the code I have developed so far but I cant get it to work. I get the error "Exception: Those rows are out of bounds. (line 218, file "macros")", line 218 is where the error falls as I have many other lines of code in this same document, here is the code I am focusing on:

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fast Fill'), true);
  var snipLoop = spreadsheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<snipLoop.length; i++){
    if(snipLoop.indexOf("ox uspe")){

      spreadsheet.deleteRow(i);

    }
  }

};
```

Again, when I run this I get the error "Exception: Those rows are out of bounds. (line 218, file "macros")". What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Based on input for user ADW I have updated my code to the following

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fast Fill'), true);
  var snipLoop = spreadsheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  for(var i = (snipLoop.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    if(snipLoop.indexOf("OX USPE") > -1){

      spreadsheet.deleteRow(i);

    }
  }

};
```

I need to further explain that the rows I am intending to delete have data values stored in columns A through E if this makes a difference.

When I run this code I get no errors and the code runs completely, however nothing happens to the activated sheet. Here I have copied and pasted the sheet name, Fast Fill, so I am certain of its accuracy in the code. Can anyone explain this?

Edit: here is an simplified example spreadsheet similar to what I am working with

```
Material    Req
CD 50S      21
CD FG20A    49
CD USP50    25
```

Comment: I posted an answer regarding this. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It did not work however I was able to take pieces from it to make a work around. I feel uncomfortable checking this as the answer since it wont exactly help the next guy. To be fair to you though I only have a basic understanding of JavaScript and as a result I have even less of an understanding of Apps Script and therefore  if I'm doing something wrong I cant consistently tell. My ability to refactor my code in Apps scripts is extremely limited so if I cant get lops to work right or variable to function correctly as arguments I switch to procedural programming which is intensive but works.

Comment: That's very strange since I tried this before posting and it was working for me. Can you be more precise on `It did not work`? The only thing I can think of is that something in your spreadsheet (something that is not present in the sample I'm using) is causing this to fail. Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you are using, free of sensitive information, so that I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have added a small sample of the spreadsheet I am working with

Comment: What I meant is a copy of the file. What you shared will not be enough to troubleshoot this. Anyway, I noticed a small problem in my script because of misunderstanding your request. You want to delete a row in which the cell in column A starts with `OX USPE`, not only that it contains this but it **starts** with this. So I changed this line `if(snipLoop[i].indexOf(textToFind) === 0){` in my answer. Also, could it be a problem of case-sensitivity? The current script will ignore cells that start with `ox uspe`, it will only look for capitalized `OX USPE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things you may want to consider:

1. If a cell does not contain "ox uspe", `snipLoop.indexOf("ox uspe")` will give a value of -1. To stop the `if` statement from deleting that row, you may need to change the statement to

   `if(snipLoop[i].indexOf("ox uspe") > -1){` [Edited]

---

2. When deleting rows, it is best to start from the bottom.

This is because of the following problem in deleting from the top: say both rows 10 and 11 need to be deleted. After row 10 has been deleted, row 11 becomes row 10. The script is reading the data from an array fetched before row 10 was deleted. So it takes row 11 needs to be delete too. But at this point, all rows have moved one up as row 10 was deleted. So instead of row 11, row 12 gets deleted.

I would suggest the following instead:

`for (var i = (snipLoop.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){`

Comment: I have updated my code however nothing occurs. The code runs without error but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. `if(snipLoop[i].indexOf("OX USPE") > -1){`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to delete the rows in which the cell in column A contains `"OX USPE"`. If that's the case, you can do this:

```js
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fast Fill');
  var textToFind = "OX USPE";
  var firstRow = 1;
  var column = 1;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var snipLoop = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, numRows).getValues().map(function(row) {
    return row[0];
  });
  for(var i = snipLoop.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(snipLoop[i].indexOf(textToFind) === 0){
      sheet.deleteRow(i + firstRow);
    }
  }
};
```

The main problem in your code is that [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a two-dimensional array. When using [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to `snipLoop` you are looking for an element in the outer array that matches the string `OX USPE`. Because each element in the outer array is actually another array (the inner array) this cannot work. It will not delete any row.

To check if a cell value contains some string, you should use [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) on each value in the inner array instead. To do that, you can (1) first, use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the 2D array into a one-dimensional array (you can do this because you are only retrieving column A, so each element in the outer array only contains an inner array with only one value, and (2) apply the `i` index to the resulting one-dimensional array.

Also, there might be a problem with the index of the rows to delete. Indexes of arrays start at 0 (`snipLoop`), but row indexes start at 0. Because of this, you should do this instead: `sheet.deleteRow(i + firstRow);`

Finally, I have modified your range a bit, so that the range is specified by indicating the `firstRow`, the `column` and the `number of rows` (see [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))) instead of using the A1 notation. This way, the script will only iterate through the rows with content, and it's easier to change the range to retrieve. I've also removed the `setActiveSheet` part, because there is no need to use this method. You can just retrieve the sheet you want by name.

#### Reference:

- [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))